# Convergence criteria of sequences of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Which of the following conditions implies (imply) the convergence of a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of real numbers?
>
> (A) Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge n_0,\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|<\varepsilon$.
>
> (B) Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge n_0,\frac1{(x+1)^2}\left|n_{n+1}-x_n\right|<\varepsilon$
>
> (C) Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $n\ge n_0, (n+1)^2\left|x_{n+1}-x_n\right|<\varepsilon$
>
> (D) Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $m,n$ $m\ge n\ge n_0,\left|x_m-x_n\right|<\varepsilon$

Could you help me find correct choices from this question? I think option c is not true but I have trouble regarding rest of the three options.

My doubt: should I solve it by taking particular examples? (which one suits best?) or there are particular theorems regarding it?

Comment: To answer your last question: You should prove that some of the propositions are _wrong_ by giving an example. You should prove that the rest are _correct_ by giving an argument including theorems and such.

Comment: If you think that the statement is correct, than you have to prove it, so you have to prove that the inequality implies the convergence. If you think the statement is not correct, than you should be able to found counterexample.

Comment: which according to  u are correct options?

Comment: All you need to know to answer this is that uniform convergence implies convergence.

Comment: Wrong terminology, I meant to say: "the real line is complete, so every cauchy sequence is convergent". Sorry about that.

Comment: Is there a typo in statement $B$? You have $n$ inside the absolute value indexed by $n+1$ and $x$ outside the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence $\{x_n\}$ is converges to $x$ if:

> For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0 \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|x-x_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

It took me a little while to really internalize this definition. I now think of the definition of convergence as "No matter how small of an $\varepsilon$ we choose, we can always go out in the sequence far enough to find an $x_{n_{0}}$ so that the difference between $x$ and any term *after* $x_{n_{0}}$ will always be less than $\varepsilon$."

Once you are comfortable with convergence, I would then recommend familiarizing yourself with Cauchy sequences. From here a very useful theorem would be to prove:

> Any (real) cauchy sequence is convergent.

When you prove that result, (or allow yourself to use that result) you will have an easy time proving/disproving $(D)$.

> For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon$.

Once you know this, you will immediately know that $\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}<\frac{1}{N+1}<\frac{1}{N}$ and this may help you deduce the truth or falsity of $(B)$ and $(C)$. It also looks like you have a counterexample for $(A)$.

Comment: so A and D are true?

Comment: I won't say yes or no yet ;) How would you argue that $(D)$ is true?

Comment: doesn't $x_n$=log(n)  counters option (A)?

Comment: logn is not convergent sequence, but option A shows it is

Comment: Indeed :). @graydad we precisely need to find a sequence for which the condition is useless (when we are trying to show the falsity of A).

Comment: @ketan Ah I had the implication backward in my mind. Yes, that is a good counterexample.

Comment: @graydad by the way I think there is a misconception in your answer, for we are given that the sequence is cauchy, so that we need to use only the completeness of the real line.

Comment: @Uzman you are right, I just changed that result. I think the rest of my answer should make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

We claim that the first two conditions do not imply the convergence of the sequence, while the latter two do imply convergence.

For A and B, simply take $\forall n: x_n:=\ln n$.

For C and D, let us first introduce a Cauchy sequence:

$\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy if $\forall\epsilon',\exists N,\forall n,m\geq N:|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon'$.

There is another practical way to say this (I'll leave it to you to prove that they are equivalent):

$\{x_n\}_n$ is Cauchy if $\forall\epsilon',\exists N,\forall n\geq N,\forall p:|x_{n+p}-x_n|<\epsilon'$.

Next, it's practical to keep in mind that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Now D says precisely that the sequence is Cauchy.

Finally let us see that C implies that the sequence is Cauchy using the alternative statement of Cauchyness. To do this we also need to recall that the $p$-series converges for $p>1$ ([see wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series)). Set $M:=\sum 1/n^2$.

Let $\epsilon'>0$. Pick $\epsilon:=\dfrac{\epsilon'}{M}>0$ in C, and let $n_0$ be the corresponding index. Set $N:=n_0$. Let $n\geq N$ and $p\in\mathbb{N}$. Then we have $|x_{n+p}-x_n|\leq|x_{n+p}-x_{n+p-1}|+...+|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{(n+p)^2}+...+\dfrac{\epsilon}{(n+1)^2} = \dfrac{\epsilon'}{M}\left(\dfrac{1}{(n+p)^2}+...+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)<\epsilon'.$ Observe that the last inequality follows from that $\left(\dfrac{1}{(n+p)^2}+...+\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$ is nothing but a part of the $2$-series (to be precise it is the difference of two partial sums).